# Getting segmentation fault with device malloc() in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda, malloc

On the call of `random_ints(b)`, the code is running into a segmentation fault after accessing `N-1` places in the array, irrelevant of the value of `N`. Though the call `random_ints(a)` works properly and assigns all the values to the array `a`. If I use static allocation of the arrays, `int a[N],b[N],c[N]` the code runs perfectly. The code is exactly same as the code provided in NVIDIA CUDA Basics tutorial other than the implementation of the `random_ints()` function. I have already tried other alternatives by replacing the function call in the `main()` or by allocating another array and returning to the `main()` from `random_ints()` or removing the CUDA snippets. Without the CUDA parts the function call runs perfectly.

I am Looking for an explanation for this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 512
__global__ void add(int *a,int *b,int *c)
{
    c[blockIdx.x]= a[blockIdx.x] + b[blockIdx.x];
}

void random_ints(int *x,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            printf("\n%d",i);
            x[i]=i;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    int *a,*b,*c;   //host copies of a,b,c
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;   //device copies of a,b,c
    int size =sizeof(int)*N;
    //Allocate memories for device copies of a,b,c
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a,size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b,size); 
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c,size);

    //Alloc space for host copies of a,b,c and setup input values
    a=(int*)malloc(size);
    random_ints(a,N);
    b=(int*)malloc(size);
    random_ints(b,N);   
    c=(int*)malloc(size);
    //copy inputs to the device 
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Launch add() kernel on GPU 
    add<<<N,1>>>(d_a,d_b,d_c);

    //copy results back to host
    cudaMemcpy(&c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
            printf("\nc= %d\n",c[i]);
    }
    //cleanup
    free(a);free(b);free(c);
    cudaFree(d_a); cudaFree(d_b); cudaFree(d_c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing incorrect arguments to `cudaMemcpy`. This:

```
cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

should be

```
cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

or

```
cudaMemcpy(d_a, &a[0], size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b, &b[0], size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

and similarly this:

```
cudaMemcpy(&c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

should be

```
cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

or

```
cudaMemcpy(&c[0], d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

It will be the device to host copy which will be the source of your problem - it will overwrite the stack and cause the segfault you are seeing.